# What is $e^{At}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, matrix-exponential

Currently, I only know how to solve systems of differential equations the eigenvector and eigenvalue way. So, one day, I decided to try something:
$$\text{Because }\vec{x}' = A\vec{x}, $$ $$\text{I solved the "differential equation" and got } \vec{x} = e^{At}.$$
What does $e^{At}$ mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Comment: Actually, you ought to have gotten $\vec x(t)=e^{At}\vec x(0)$ instead of  $\vec x(t)=e^{At}$.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in order to "extend" functions to other than real numbers, we use the "Taylor series".  In particular, $e^t= \sum \frac{1}{n!}t^n$.  So we can define $e^{At}= \sum \frac{1}{n!}A^nt^n$

Comment: How do you find so much exponentials of A and then add them together?

Comment: If A is a diagonalizable matrix, that is, there exist an invertible matrix, B,  such that $A= BDB^{-1}$  then $A^n= (BDB^{-1})(BDB^{-1})\cdot\cdot\cdot(BDB^{-1})= BD^nB^{-1}$.  And, since D is diagonal, $D^n$ is just the diagonal matrix with the nth powers of the diagonal elements of D on the diagonal. And the sum $c_0I+ c_1A+ c_2A^2+ \cdot\cdot+ c_nA^n= B(c_0I+ c_1D+ c_2D^2+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ c_nD^n)B^{-1}$.   If A is **not** diagonal, there exist such a B so that D is in "Jordan Normal Form".  That make the computation a little harder but still doable.